# JPA: Left join not working with "is null" in where clause

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, left-join, isnull

I am using EclipseLink (2.4, 2.5 and 2.6) on a very simple project where I have a `Department` entity and each `Department` links to an `Employee` entity which is the `manager` of the `Department`.

I am currently unable to make this simple query work:

```
select d from Department d where d.manager is null
```

Returns 1 row

```
select d from Department d left join fetch d.manager where d.manager is null
```

Returns 0 row

I am using Eclipselink over an H2 database. The SQL query generated does not seem to create a left join but rather an inner join which obviously will fail.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.MANAGER_ID, t0.ID, t0.NAME FROM EMPLOYEE t0, DEPARTMENT t1
WHERE ((t1.MANAGER_ID IS NULL) AND (t0.ID = t1.MANAGER_ID))
```

Is this a bug or is it something wanted? Or could someone help me fixing this?

Happy to provide the code and example if anyone wants it, or more information.

Comment: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_

Comment: try using the fetch-join query hint described here:http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints#Join_Fetch instead of using it in the JPQL.  The parser seems to be seeing the d.manager in there twice and so building an inner join - you might file a bug for this as the two joins should be independent

Comment: @Chris adding this `query.setHint(QueryHints.LEFT_FETCH, "d.manager");` did not change the results. However, using this query `select d from Department d left join d.manager m where m is null` actually works but it seems a bit far fetched.

Comment: The reason it works is that specifying d.manager in the where clause requires an inner join.  When the relationship isn't used anywhere else, EclipseLink can tell that the relationship itself isn't needed, only the foreign key, and so doesn't join.  When you use the relationship elsewhere, the d.manager inner join trumps any other join, so the inner join is used instead.  By using m is null, you are forcing it to use the outer join logic.  Specifying the outer join is the proper way to do it in JPA as some relations need a join to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unsafe to reference an entity that was returned in a query as a side effect by using a `FETCH JOIN`. The JPA specification tries to prohibit such queries at least for multi-valued associations (JSR 338, section 4.4.5.3):

> It is not permitted to specify an identification variable for the objects referenced by the right side of the `FETCH JOIN` clause, and hence **references to the implicitly fetched entities or elements cannot appear** elsewhere in the query.

Your query executed on EclipseLink and Hibernate yields different results (EclipseLink 2.6.3: no results, Hibernate 4.3.11: all departments with no manager):

```
select d from Department d left join fetch d.manager where d.manager is null
```

To solve your problem a subquery could be used. A portable JPQL query could look like this (same results in EclipseLink and Hibernate):

```
select d1 from Department d1 left join fetch d1.manager where exists 
(select d2 from Department d2 where d2.manager is null and d1 = d2)
```