# Spot another JPA weird case (added a selected attribute completly changes the resultset of the query)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink

Given this query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT lc.id, lc.debtor.officialCompanyName, lc.liquidationPublicationDate, lc.regNumberLegalRepresentative, lc.regNumberLiquidatorCompany, lc.liquidationStatusType, "
                    + "lc.authority, lc.liquidationSupervisor, lc.liquidationFinalizationDate, lc.finalReportFilingDate "
                    + "FROM LiquidationCase lc "
                        + "WHERE lc.active = 1 AND (lc.clerk = :user "
                            + "OR :user MEMBER OF lc.endemicSite.company.managers "
                            + "OR :user MEMBER OF lc.endemicSite.managers) "
                            + "AND lc.endemicSite.id = :endemicSiteId ")"
```

If I **add** **lc.clerk** to the **selected attributes**, like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT lc.id, lc.debtor.officialCompanyName, lc.liquidationPublicationDate, lc.regNumberLegalRepresentative, lc.regNumberLiquidatorCompany, lc.liquidationStatusType, "
                    + "lc.authority, lc.clerk, lc.liquidationSupervisor, lc.liquidationFinalizationDate, lc.finalReportFilingDate "
                    + "FROM LiquidationCase lc "
                        + "WHERE lc.active = 1 AND (lc.clerk = :user "
                            + "OR :user MEMBER OF lc.endemicSite.company.managers "
                            + "OR :user MEMBER OF lc.endemicSite.managers) "
                            + "AND lc.endemicSite.id = :endemicSiteId "
```

then the **lc-s which has a clerk with null value will** not be selected, however I would like to get these lc-s (liquidCases). Somehow the generated query is just not good.

Any idea how to solve this issue (Kindly ask not to mention the post-process clerk selecting from DB)?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

More info:

**1st generated query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.id,
                t1.official_company_name,
                t0.liquidation_publication_date,
                t0.reg_number_legal_representative,
                t0.reg_number_liquidator_company,
                t0.liquidation_status_type,
                t2.id,
                t2.active,
                t2.created_on,
                t2.deactivated_on,
                t2.department_name,
                t2.last_modified_on,
                t2.mask_agreement,
                t2.mask_closing_order,
                t2.mask_closing_order_publication,
                t2.mask_company_register,
                t2.mask_designation,
                t2.mask_disclosure,
                t2.mask_injunction,
                t2.mask_interim_financial_report,
                t2.mask_legal_representative,
                t2.name,
                t2.note,
                t2.is_persisted,
                t2.primary_fax,
                t2.primary_phone,
                t2.authority_type_id,
                t2.created_by_id,
                t2.deactivated_by_id,
                t2.last_modified_by_id,
                t2.address_id,
                t2.mailing_address_id,
                t2.primary_authority_email_address_id,
                t3.id,
                t3.active,
                t3.created_on,
                t3.deactivated_on,
                t3.last_modified_on,
                t3.is_persisted,
                t3.created_by_id,
                t3.deactivated_by_id,
                t3.last_modified_by_id,
                t3.personal_data_id,
                t0.liquidation_finalization_date,
                t0.final_report_filing_date
FROM liquidator.liquidation_case t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.authority t2 ON (t2.id = t0.authority_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.liquidation_supervisor t3 ON (t3.id = t0.liquidation_supervisor), liquidator.site_manager_user_site t9,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_company t8,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t7,
                                                                                             liquidator.site t6,
                                                                                             liquidator.company t5,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t4,
                                                                                             liquidator.debtor t1
WHERE ((((t0.active = ?)
         AND (((t0.clerk_id = ?)
               OR (? = t4.id))
              OR (? = t7.id)))
        AND (t0.endemic_site_id = ?))
       AND (((((t6.id = t0.endemic_site_id)
               AND (t5.id = t6.company_id))
              AND ((t8.company_id = t5.id)
                   AND (t4.id = t8.user_id)))
             AND ((t9.site_id = t6.id)
                  AND (t7.id = t9.user_id)))
            AND (t1.id = t0.debtor_id)))
```

**2nd generated query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.id,
                t1.official_company_name,
                t0.liquidation_publication_date,
                t0.reg_number_legal_representative,
                t0.reg_number_liquidator_company,
                t0.liquidation_status_type,
                t2.id,
                t2.active,
                t2.created_on,
                t2.deactivated_on,
                t2.department_name,
                t2.last_modified_on,
                t2.mask_agreement,
                t2.mask_closing_order,
                t2.mask_closing_order_publication,
                t2.mask_company_register,
                t2.mask_designation,
                t2.mask_disclosure,
                t2.mask_injunction,
                t2.mask_interim_financial_report,
                t2.mask_legal_representative,
                t2.name,
                t2.note,
                t2.is_persisted,
                t2.primary_fax,
                t2.primary_phone,
                t2.authority_type_id,
                t2.created_by_id,
                t2.deactivated_by_id,
                t2.last_modified_by_id,
                t2.address_id,
                t2.mailing_address_id,
                t2.primary_authority_email_address_id,
                t3.id,
                t3.active,
                t3.created_on,
                t3.deactivated_on,
                t3.end_of_session,
                t3.surname,
                t3.forename,
                t3.last_login,
                t3.last_logout,
                t3.last_modified_on,
                t3.locked_on,
                t3.note,
                t3.password,
                t3.is_persisted,
                t3.phone_number,
                t3.role,
                t3.transaction_code,
                t3.username,
                t3.created_by_id,
                t3.deactivated_by_id,
                t3.last_modified_by_id,
                t3.address_id,
                t3.user_email_address_id,
                t3.locked_by,
                t3.login_site,
                t4.id,
                t4.active,
                t4.created_on,
                t4.deactivated_on,
                t4.last_modified_on,
                t4.is_persisted,
                t4.created_by_id,
                t4.deactivated_by_id,
                t4.last_modified_by_id,
                t4.personal_data_id,
                t0.liquidation_finalization_date,
                t0.final_report_filing_date
FROM liquidator.liquidation_case t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.authority t2 ON (t2.id = t0.authority_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.liquidation_supervisor t4 ON (t4.id = t0.liquidation_supervisor), liquidator.site_manager_user_site t10,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_company t9,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t8,
                                                                                             liquidator.site t7,
                                                                                             liquidator.company t6,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t5,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t3,
                                                                                             liquidator.debtor t1
WHERE ((((t0.active = ?)
         AND (((t0.clerk_id = ?)
               OR (? = t5.id))
              OR (? = t8.id)))
        AND (t0.endemic_site_id = ?))
       AND ((((((t7.id = t0.endemic_site_id)
                AND (t6.id = t7.company_id))
               AND ((t9.company_id = t6.id)
                    AND (t5.id = t9.user_id)))
              AND ((t10.site_id = t7.id)
                   AND (t8.id = t10.user_id)))
             AND (t1.id = t0.debtor_id))
            AND (t3.id = t0.clerk_id)))
```

**UPDATE**:

OK. So the good query would be, like this:

How can I tell JPA to use this query, use left join instead of a where condition??!?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t0.id,
                t1.official_company_name,
                t0.liquidation_publication_date,
                t0.reg_number_legal_representative,
                t0.reg_number_liquidator_company,
                t0.liquidation_status_type,
                t2.id,
                t2.active,
                t2.created_on,
                t2.deactivated_on,
                t2.department_name,
                t2.last_modified_on,
                t2.mask_agreement,
                t2.mask_closing_order,
                t2.mask_closing_order_publication,
                t2.mask_company_register,
                t2.mask_designation,
                t2.mask_disclosure,
                t2.mask_injunction,
                t2.mask_interim_financial_report,
                t2.mask_legal_representative,
                t2.name,
                t2.note,
                t2.is_persisted,
                t2.primary_fax,
                t2.primary_phone,
                t2.authority_type_id,
                t2.created_by_id,
                t2.deactivated_by_id,
                t2.last_modified_by_id,
                t2.address_id,
                t2.mailing_address_id,
                t2.primary_authority_email_address_id,
                t3.id,
                t3.active,
                t3.created_on,
                t3.deactivated_on,
                t3.end_of_session,
                t3.surname,
                t3.forename,
                t3.last_login,
                t3.last_logout,
                t3.last_modified_on,
                t3.locked_on,
                t3.note,
                t3.password,
                t3.is_persisted,
                t3.phone_number,
                t3.role,
                t3.transaction_code,
                t3.username,
                t3.created_by_id,
                t3.deactivated_by_id,
                t3.last_modified_by_id,
                t3.address_id,
                t3.user_email_address_id,
                t3.locked_by,
                t3.login_site,
                t4.id,
                t4.active,
                t4.created_on,
                t4.deactivated_on,
                t4.last_modified_on,
                t4.is_persisted,
                t4.created_by_id,
                t4.deactivated_by_id,
                t4.last_modified_by_id,
                t4.personal_data_id,
                t0.liquidation_finalization_date,
                t0.final_report_filing_date
FROM liquidator.liquidation_case t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.authority t2 ON (t2.id = t0.authority_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.liquidation_supervisor t4 ON (t4.id = t0.liquidation_supervisor) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN liquidator.user_entity t3 ON (t3.id = t0.clerk_id),                         liquidator.site_manager_user_site t10,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_company t9,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t8,
                                                                                             liquidator.site t7,
                                                                                             liquidator.company t6,
                                                                                             liquidator.user_entity t5,
                                                                                             liquidator.debtor t1
WHERE ((((t0.active = ?)
         AND (((t0.clerk_id = ?)
               OR (? = t5.id))
              OR (? = t8.id)))
        AND (t0.endemic_site_id = ?))
       AND ((((((t7.id = t0.endemic_site_id)
                AND (t6.id = t7.company_id))
               AND ((t9.company_id = t6.id)
                    AND (t5.id = t9.user_id)))
              AND ((t10.site_id = t7.id)
                   AND (t8.id = t10.user_id)))
             AND (t1.id = t0.debtor_id))
            AND (true)));
```

Comment: AND (t3.id = t0.clerk_id))) at the very last condition seems problematic, should be removed and everything would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clerk is a relationship mapping, so if you want the query to include null, you will need to tell it to use an outer join over the relationship:

```
Select clerk, ... From LiquidationCase lc left join lc.clerk clerk...
```

Comment: exactly the same solution, which I used based on this stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509686/jpa-left-join-not-working-with-is-null-in-where-clause

So we can count this one as a duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT lc.id, lc.debtor.officialCompanyName, lc.liquidationPublicationDate, lc.regNumberLegalRepresentative, lc.regNumberLiquidatorCompany, lc.liquidationStatusType, "
                    + "lc.authority, lc.clerk, lc.liquidationSupervisor, lc.liquidationFinalizationDate, lc.finalReportFilingDate "
                    + "FROM LiquidationCase lc "
                        + "WHERE lc.active = 1 AND (lc.clerk IS NULL OR lc.clerk = :user "
                            + "OR :user MEMBER OF lc.endemicSite.company.managers "
                            + "OR :user MEMBER OF lc.endemicSite.managers) "
                            + "AND lc.endemicSite.id = :endemicSiteId "
```

Comment: you mean OK = OR ?:) Anyway upvoted because the efforts!

Comment: Anyway this logic is not exactly which I wanted to get.

Comment: @czupe yep, fixed the typo; which results you expected?

Comment: My condition should be (in free words)
user is a clerk 
OR 
user is a company manager
OR
user is a company owner (manager)
---
But in you condition i will also get the cases which has no clerk, and this is no good. But thanks for your work, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Very nice answer from Chris in another topic ([JPA: Left join not working with "is null" in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509686/jpa-left-join-not-working-with-is-null-in-where-clause)):

> "The reason it works is that specifying d.manager in the where clause
>   requires an inner join. When the relationship isn't used anywhere
>   else, EclipseLink can tell that the relationship itself isn't needed,
>   only the foreign key, and so doesn't join. When you use the
>   relationship elsewhere, the d.manager inner join trumps any other
>   join, so the inner join is used instead. By using m is null, you are
>   forcing it to use the outer join logic. Specifying the outer join is
>   the proper way to do it in JPA as some relations need a join to
>   resolve. "

In our case we can substitue the `d.manager` with `lc.clerk`.

Wow. You are the same person : ) If you copy your comment to your answer I will delete my answer.